# Checking the type of variable in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to check the type of variable in Jinja2. If it is type of variable is dictionary then I have to print some text in the paragraph and if it's not dict then I have to print some other values.

What I tried here is

```
{% if {{result}} is dict %}
<tr>
<td>
<p> The details are not here </p>
</td>
</tr>
{% else %}
{% for each_value in result %}
<tr>
<td>each_value.student_name</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The result I get is two different ways one is of dict type

```
I.result={'student_name':'a','student_id':1,'student_email':'my_name@gmail.com'}
```

the another format of result is

```
II.result=[{'student_name':'b','student_id':2,'student_email':'my_nameb@gmail.com','time':[{'st':1,'et':2},{'st':3,'et':4}]}]
```

```
Expected result
If I get the format 'I' then the if loop should get execute.
If I get the format 'II' then the else loop should get execute.
```

```
Actual result
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `{% if {{result}} is dict %}` with `{% if result is mapping %}`.

[Reference](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#mapping)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, and more general solutions, in the sense that it will work not only for mappings, but any type:

`{% if result.__class__.__name__ == "dict" %}`

or [add isinstance to Jinja context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62167968/how-use-python-function-in-flask-jinja2-template#answer-62169104), and then

`{% if isinstance(result, dict) %}`