# How use python function in flask jinja2 template?

Tags: python, html, user-interface, flask, jinja2

I am sending one list of list to my HTML page, using flask jinja2 template. I want to check:- is item in list is of type str or not ?. But getting an exception of

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'isinstance' is undefined

Code is as below:-

```
{% for i in req%}

    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{loop.index}}</th>
        <td>{{i[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{i[24]}}</td>
        <td>{{i[49]}}</td>
        <td>{{i[53]}}</td>
        {% if isinstance(i[86], str) %}
            {% for j in i[86].split(",") %}
                <ol>
                    <li>{{i[86]}}</li>
                </ol>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <td>{{i[86]}}</td>
        {% endif %}

    </tr>

    {% endfor %}
```

I am able to use `split(",")` function and Want to use `isinstance()` or `str()`  of python in jinja 2 template.

Comment: Even though it looks like Python, it's actually Jinja2 syntax and you can only use one of the builtin [tests](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests) or [functions](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-global-functions). Anything not in those lists you'll need to [define](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#custom-tests) [yourself](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#jinja2.Environment.globals).

Comment: To add upon @deceze's comment, you can also register your own custom Jinja2 template filters using Flask: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#registering-filters

Answer (score 5):

The language in the jinja template is not actually python, it's python like looking, it means python built-ins are not present. To make python built-ins present in every template, at startup, add any required built-ins to the `globals` parameter when building the `jinja2.Environment`. Something like below:

```py
app.jinja_env.globals.update(isinstance=isinstance)
```

or

```py
import jinja2
env = jinja2.Environment()
env.globals.update(isinstance:isinstance)
```

Comment: 'app.jinja_env.globals.update(isinstance=isinstance)' worked for me. Can I register more methods over there like 'app.jinja_env.globals.update(isinstance=isinstance, sorted = soreted)'. Got syntax error' env.globals.update(isinstance:isinstance)' for next solution.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, by `soreted` you mean `sorted`? Is this a typo?

Comment: You might run into the followup problem of the need to import the type to avoid TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828406/import-a-python-module-into-a-jinja-template

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a [Flask context processor](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/templating/#context-processors). For example, from the Flask docs, here is a context processor that makes a `format_price` function available in all templates in the application:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def format_price(amount, currency="€"):
        return f"{amount:.2f}{currency}"
    return dict(format_price=format_price)
```

The idea is that you decorate a function with `@app.context_processor` and then the dictionary it returns in automagically merged into the Jinja context for all templates.

Note that this can even be used to [add entire modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68906361/470844) to the template context.